# blank Kivy window opens at random

Tags: python, kivy

I'm developing a python app using **Kivy**.

Sometimes when I'm launching other python scripts without kivy imports a blank Kivy window opens randomly without any reason.

Is this a bug? Or am I missing something on the app closing?

I've seen this strange behaviour only under Windows (8), **Python 2.7**.
The window is completely white and seems not responding (I know it's a Kivy window from the little icon on the top-left corner), few seconds later the system says `python.exe has stopped working`.

Comment: So you are running other python scripts which have nothing to do with kivy, but then sometimes an empty kivy window opens? Can you show us a script which does that? Maybe you import some util functions where you added kivy in an virtualenv and only if you are in that venv that happens or something like that?

Comment: @syntonym yes, I'll try to get more information about the problem and update the question, is not simple to reproduce because seems really random

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug. You have to add child widgets e.g. button, label, textinput, etc. into your root widget. Please refer to example below for details.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout


class MyRootWidget(FloatLayout):
    pass


class TestApp(App):
    title = "Kivy Demo"

    def build(self):
        return MyRootWidget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<MyRootWidget>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: [1, 1, 1, 1]    # White color
        Rectangle:
            size: self.width, self.height
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            font_size: 50
            text: "[color=ff3333][b]Hello[/b][/color]"
            markup: True
        Label:
            font_size: 20
            text: "[color=3333ff]World[/color]"
            markup: True
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the problem, I know how to show some widgets etc, I understand that my sample code was too simple and maybe misleading, I'll update the question to make it more clear. Thank you for the detailed example though.